# Add more functions to the home button circle shortcut

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, home-screen-shortcuts, home-button

When you swipe up from the home button in Jelly Bean you get a cute
semicircle with a Google Now shortcut on top. This circle shape
makes it perfect for adding other shortcuts.

For instance, you could have the Gmail icon on the left side of the
circle and the Chrome icon on the right side.

Is there any way to get this functionality (different launcher, some
rooted app, different ROM)?

Comment: What phone do you want to MOD?

Comment: It's a nexus4. System version 4.2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this functionality with these launchers:

1. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sudomakemeanapp.sudoquicklaunch
2. http://www.droid-life.com/2013/01/23/lmt-launcher-brings-pie-goodness-without-the-custom-rom/